# How to create pie chart with pyqtgraph.GraphicsWindow and create custom scale in x axis

Tags: python, charts, pyqtgraph

I am doing a project that needs to create some piecharts with pyqtgraph library. I can make column charts and line charts using the pyqtgraph.GraphicsWindow,but I can't find out how to create a piechart. Are there some methods that can help me to accomplish that？

Another problem, I don't know how to change the x Axis scale by some discrete settings. For example, when I make a column chart, I want to set a number '5' to the first column, '7' to the second column,'16' to the third column.....how can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, pyqtgraph has no built-in pie chart graphics. However, these should be fairly simple to construct by creating one [QGraphicsEllipseItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsellipseitem.html) for each wedge.

For the second, use the following:

```
majorTickValues = [(0,"5"),(1,"7"),(2,"16")]
plotItem.getAxis('bottom').setTicks([majorTickValues])
```